# Cannot update resultset in JDBC

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

```
com.mysql.jdbc.NotUpdatable: Result Set not updatable.
```

> This result set must come from a statement that was created with a
>   result set type of  ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE, the query must select
>   only one table, can  not use functions and must select all primary
>   keys from that table.  See the JDBC 2.1 API Specification, section 5.6
>   for more details.
>
> This result set must come from a statement that was created with a
>   result  set type of ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE, the query must select
>   only one  table, can not use functions and must select all primary
>   keys from  that table. See the JDBC 2.1 API Specification, section 5.6
>   for more  details.

Above is the error I am getting. I have a primary key on my table. I see `ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE`, do I need to use a different object if I want to update the resultset?

Comment: Is that message coming twice in your error? Have a look at http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8527 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908646/problem-with-adding-rows-with-jdbc-and-mysql

Comment: Yes it is coming twice. I do not believe the resultset is updatable, how do I make it so?

Comment: I have read that second link and like I said, I have primary keys in my table.

Comment: You must show the actual query.  You can set `CONCUR_UPDATABLE` but updatable queries must satisfy some significant constraints.

Comment: @Austin Johnston: Provide the code where you are trying to update.

Comment: And more importantly: show the code how you create and execute the statement.